# how to make `git --bare` with all files within `.git/`

Tags: git, git-bare, .git-folder

I am using bare repositories in addition to `git worktree add` to manage to handle multiple branches at the same time.

It turns out `git clone --bare` moves all files from `.git/` to `./`, and it is very hard to look for the added branches among all the files of `.git/` in `./`.

My goal is to have the following tree structure:

```
./
├── .git/
├── branch1/
├── branch2/
└── branch3/
.
.
.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What do you expect `branch1/` to contain? A worktree?

Comment: @mkrieger1 the files and directories of the branch `branch1`

Answer (score 1):

Directories containing bare repositories are by convention named `<project name>.git`.

You can just rename and move the directories containing the bare repository, and the different worktrees, to a common parent directory.

```
parent/
├── project.git/
├── branch1/
├── branch2/
└── branch3/
```

Naming the bare repository `.git` would make the `parent` directory into a Git repository, which you explicitly don't want.

Comment: It worked here if I name `.git/` instead of `bare.git/`, Edit your answer to mark it as the solution :)

Comment: ^ That doesn't make any sense. If you rename `bare.git` to `.git`, you end up with the exact same structure you started with. The answer here even explicitly states that making use of the name `.git` is the problem...

Comment: @ObsidianAge "If you rename `bare.git` to `.git`, you end up with the exact same structure you started with." no, I do not start with this structure, actually my goal is the reach this structure. It is clearly stated in my question.